# Regex Multi-Line: IP Correction

Tags: regex

I've got a list of ip addresses in the form ip:port, but some of them are malformed, eg like so:

```
OCTETS ARE EXAMPLES, It doesn't matter that they are over 255
12.345.678.90:12345
58412.345.678.91:12391
12.345.678.92:1823
12.345.678.93:80
```

I want to strip out the extra numbers from the 2nd IP, using regex, as it occurs very often, and I have ~2000 of these to filter through

My first thought was to find: `\r\n[0-9]{3,15}(.*\r\n[0-9]{1,3})` and replace with `\2\1\2`, but it seems to have no effect.

I've had to presume the next line has the same leading digits, which is doesn't NECESSARILY have to. If anyone could show me a solution that only repairs it if the next line leads with the digits contained before the dot, that would be appreciated greatly.

EDIT: I'm using Notepad++ for this Regex

Also, even if you use octet detection, what if the numbers I want are say, 12, and the first octet is 112?

Comment: All of those are invalid IP adresses, each octet needs to be between 0 and 255, inclusive.

Comment: Judging by the fact without dots, it goes 1234567890, might you not consider that it is an example?

Comment: I get that, but any answer that works with your example validates IP addresses incorrectly.

Comment: the first octet is the only number that is malformed, so the others can be assumed to be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing `^\d+(\d{2}\.)` with `\1`

Comment: Came up as an invalid Regex :(

Comment: I think the positions of \ and `(` are switched.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})`

This should match any valid IP address. (IE. not "257.4.33.134" because 257 is too big)

Note: this would match none of your examples, because the octets are too big

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Matches the IP, but not the port, but the main issue is the misformed octet which I need to use the next line to fix.

Comment: this regex would return 45.67.89.12 from 12345.67.89.12, which seems to be what you are asking for, I don't know why you would accept an answer that matches a malformed IP, though

Comment: What would your regex provide from 84174.71.37.17 though? Validation of the octet isn't needed in this case is all.

Comment: it would match '174.71.37.17' from '84174.71.37.17'